# Spark Dataset Loading multiple CSV files with headers inside a folder and report mismatch in case the headers in all the files are not same

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

I am trying to load multiple csv files from a hdfs directory into spark DataSet using Spark 2.1.0 APIs:

```
val csvData = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("csvdatatest/")
```

Inside the "csvdatatest" folder there are multiple csv files. Spark is picking header only from the first file and generating this as Schema of the DataSet ignoring the header for remaining csv files. e.g

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/kumara91/csvdatatest
Found 2 items
/user/kumara91/csvdatatest/controlfile-2017-10-19.csv
/user/kumara91/csvdatatest/controlfile-2017-10-23.csv

hadoop fs -cat /user/kumara91/csvdatatest/controlfile-2017-10-19.csv
Delivery ID,BroadLog ID,Channel,Address,Event type,Event date,File name

hadoop fs -cat /user/kumara91/csvdatatest/controlfile-2017-10-23.csv
Delivery ID,BroadLog ID,Channel,Address,Event type,Event date,File name,dummycolumn

scala> val csvData = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv("csvdatatest/")
csvData: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [Delivery ID: string, BroadLog ID: string ... 5 more fields]

scala> csvData.schema.fieldNames
res1: Array[String] = Array(Delivery ID, BroadLog ID, Channel, Address, Event type, Event date, File name)
```

Here, it loaded the header only from the file "controlfile-2017-10-19.csv" and ignored the header with extra column "dummycolumn" in other csv file.

But my requirement is to compare the headers of all the csv files in the folder. 
And load the files only if all the CSV files contains the same header. Report mismatch in case and csv file contain more or less or different header

I have the option to do this using the regular hdfs filesystem APIs. And then use Spark APIs. Or other option to Read all the csv files one by one using Spark APIs and do the comparison.

But, I wanted to know if there is any way using the Spark APIs i can achieve without iterating over each of the files.And also, why spark read header from one file and ignores the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways to read the data correctly without iterating over the files in some way. In big data, file-based data sources are directory-based and the assumption for CSV is that all files in a directory have the same schema. There is no equivalent to `.read.option("mergeSchema", true)` that exists for JSON sources.

If you want to check just the headers, you will need to process the files one at a time. After you get a listing of all the files, using whichever method you want, the easiest thing to do is grab the headers using something like:

```
val paths: Seq[String] = ...
val pathsAndHeaders: Seq[(String, String)] = paths.map { path =>
  val header = sc.textFile(path).take(1).collect.head
  (path, header)
}
```

A more efficient version, if you have many CSVs is to distribute the paths across the cluster but then you'll have to read the file yourself:

```
val paths: Seq[String] = ...
val pathsAndHeaders: Seq[(String, String)] = sc.parallelize(paths)
  .map { path =>
    val header = // read first line of file at path
    (path, header)
  }
  .collect
```

Now that you have the paths and the headers, do whatever you need. For example, once you group the files into groups with the same header you can pass a sequence of paths to `load()` to read them in one operation.

Comment: I have already mentioned in the question that, by using the way you explained above the problem can be solved . But, my question was weather it can be achieved without doing the listing of the files inside the folder. And the major concern here was, Spark creates a illusion of the schema by reading from only one file and not the considering the rest.

Comment: There are no ways to read the data correctly without iterating over the files in some way. The code I provided above is the simplest possible approach. Once you group the files into groups with the same header you can pass a sequence of paths to `load()` to read them in one operation. In big data, file-based data sources are directory-based and the assumption for CSV is that all files in a directory have the same schema. There is no equivalent to `.read.option("mergeSchema", true)` that exists for JSON sources.

Answer (score -2):

It automatically merges, and show the latest schema.
For data missing columns is shown as nulls.
I am using spark version 2.3.1

Comment: This does not answer the question of how to validate the headers.